# $GET, PHP - Error: Undefined index: path

Tags: php, get

i want to display the filepath in another window  but i dont know what to do. please help. thank you!

in search_form.php

```
<td><a href="items.php?filepath=' .urlencode($path). '"onClick="MM_openBrWindow(\'items.php?filepath=' .urlencode($path). '\',\'window\',\'width=650,height=500\'); return false;"> <img src="Folder-Blank-icon.png"> </a></td>
```

in items.php

```
$filepath = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['path']);
echo $filepath;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$filepath = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['filepath']);
```

Your `items.php` is looking for the parameter `?path=` but you are navigating the user to `?filepath`

Comment: @user2335183 if this has solved your issue you can use the green arrow under the up/down vote to mark it as the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$filepath = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['filepath']);
echo $filepath;
```

This is because in your form you have:

```
<a href="items.php?filepath=...
```

so you need to use `$_GET['filepath']` not `$_GET['file']`.